How to combine image filters in Firemonkey?
The TFilterHueAdjust only allows modiyfying the Hue of a bitmap. How can we update it to apply Saturation and Light (HSL?)
procedure AdjustHSL(Source, Dest: TBitmap; H, S, L: Single);
var
  Filter: TFilterHueAdjust;
begin
  Filter := TFilterHueAdjust.Create(nil);
  try
    Filter.Input := Source;
    Filter.Hue := H;
    Dest.Assign(Filter.Output);
  finally
    Filter.Free;
  end;
end;

I tried applying Brightness and Contrast seperately using TFilterContrast but changing it loses the Hue (seems only one filter can be applied at a time?).
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Use the InputFilter property to chain multiple filters, eg:
procedure AdjustHSL(Source, Dest: TBitmap; H, S, L: Single);
var
  HueFilter: TFilterHueAdjust;
  ContrastFilter: TFilterContrast;
begin
  HueFilter := TFilterHueAdjust.Create(nil);
  try
    HueFilter.Input := Source;
    HueFilter.Hue := H;
    ContrastFilter := TFilterContrast.Create(nil);
    try
      ContrastFilter.InputFilter := HueFilter; // <--
      ContrastFilter.Brightness := L;
      Dest.Assign(ContrastFilter.Output);
    finally
      ContrastFilter.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HueFilter.Free;
  end;
end;

